# Difficulty slicing a tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to reduce an input sequence tensor to be just the last element of the sequence, but it doesn't appear to apply the change:

```
tf.print(f'EncoderLayer.call.query: {query}')
newquery = query[:][-1:][:]
tf.print(f'EncoderLayer.call.newquery: {newquery}')
```

result:

```
EncoderLayer.call.query: Tensor("test_model_36/dense_291/BiasAdd:0", shape=(None, 512, 512), dtype=float32)
EncoderLayer.call.newquery: Tensor("test_model_36/decoder_layer_0/strided_slice_2:0", shape=(None, 512, 512), dtype=float32)
```

If anybody's curious, I'm doing this to implement an idea from this paper: [Last Query Transformer RNN for knowledge tracing](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2102.05038.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line:

```
newquery = query[:, -1:]
```